# Javascript: Capture Id of right click element

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that is working great, but it addresses only one Id (headline11). The problem is that I can have many Id's (headline11, headline12, headline13,...). I can get the Id of the right-clicked element see my fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/yagami889/xpvt214o/471009/ but I can't make it work for my piece of code, I get a bunch of jQuery errors. This is what I'm trying to do to start with my testings:

```
var idHeadline = "";

$('input').contextmenu(function() { 
            idHeadline = $(this).attr('id');
        });

$("#" + idHeadline).on("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#cntnr").css({"left": e.pageX-3, "top": e.pageY-3});
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200, startFocusOut);

});

function startFocusOut(){
  $("#cntnr").on("click",function(){
  $("#cntnr").hide();        
  $("#cntnr").off("click");
  });
}

$("#items > li").click(function(){
$("#" + idHeadline).val($(this).text().replace("fallback", " "));
var input1 = $("#" + idHeadline);
setInputSelection(input1, 9, 10);
});
```

This is the working code:

```
$("#headline11").on("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#cntnr").css({"left": e.pageX-3, "top": e.pageY-3});
  $("#cntnr").fadeIn(200, startFocusOut);

});

function startFocusOut(){
  $("#cntnr").on("click",function(){
  $("#cntnr").hide();        
  $("#cntnr").off("click");
  });
}

$("#items > li").click(function(){
$("#headline11").val($(this).text().replace("fallback", " "));
var input1 = $("#headline11");
setInputSelection(input1, 9, 10);
});
```

Thank you for your help,

Comment: what are those bunch of errors ?

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation instead, so that you can listen to right clicks on the whole `document`, check to see if the clicked element is an `input`, and if so, run the appropriate function, no IDs needed:

```js
$(document).on("contextmenu", 'input[id^="headline"]', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('running some function');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="headline11" type="text" />
<input id="headline12" type="text" />
<input id="notaheadline" type="text" />
```

For your `items` listeners, you can do the same sort of thing - add just one listener instead of many:

```
$("#items").on("click", 'li', function(){
  $(this).val($(this).text().replace("fallback", " "));
  // etc
});
```

Comment: I've other inputs that I don't want my code to run for, Only ids that contain headline1+x. Thank you anyway.

Comment: See edit - just add the appropriate selector, make sure the `input`'s `id` starts with `headline`

Comment: How can I use the attribute selected inside the function?

Comment: What do you mean, `the attribute selected`? You haven't posted any of the HTML you're actually using, so it's not clear what you want. You can `$(this).attr('id')` to get the ID of the clicked element

Comment: The html is the same as posted,the only difference is I have many input with the id increments (headline11, headline12, headline13, headline14...), Your answer helps a bit as I can run my code by id selected, the only set back I have is how to put the other 2 functions in the one you created as they also use $(this). Won't that create a conflict? Sorry, I'm an early beginner trying to code in Javascript.

Comment: Your HTML definitely doesn't match just what you posted in the fiddle - you clearly have an `#items` element as well as a list with `li`s inside them, in addition to a `#cntnr` element. But nothing of the sort exists in the your fiddle. `this` refers to the calling context of the function - it's not a standard variable.

Comment: Sorry, I responded too quickly without testing your code. It works great, You wouldn't have needed all the code to help me and you did great. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I can get the the selected value on the context menu to add to the right id. Here is what I've done :

Comment: $(document).on("contextmenu", 'input[id^="headline1"]', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var attributeId = $(this).attr('id');
$("#cntnr").css({"left": e.pageX-3, "top": e.pageY-3});
$("#cntnr").fadeIn(200, startFocusOut);
 function startFocusOut(){
$("#cntnr").on("click",function(){
$("#cntnr").hide();        
$("#cntnr").off("click");
      });
    }
$("#items > li").click(function(){
    $("#" + attributeId).val($(this).text().replace("fallback", " "));
var input1 = $("#" + attributeId);
setInputSelection(input1, 9, 10);
    });
    });

Comment: Here is a fiddle created for an earlier question https://jsfiddle.net/yagami889/xpvt214o/470697/ this might help you. Thank you again.